# it is possible to remove sidebar for specific category product listing?

Tags: magento2, product, category, category-listing

my file : `Vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/category/products.phtml`
i made this changes 
`

```
if($category_name == 'Featured Product'){?>
     <!--  when Featured Products -->
            <style>
           .sidebar{
                    display:none;

            }
            .toolbar{
                display:none;
            }
        </style>
       <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('featured_product_top')->toHtml(); ?>

        <?php if (!$block->isContentMode() || $block->isMixedMode()): ?>
            <?= $block->getProductListHtml() ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?}else{?>
    <!--  other ctegories -->
    <?php
        /**
         * Category view template
         *
         * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View
         */
        ?>
        <?php if (!$block->isContentMode() || $block->isMixedMode()): ?>
            <?= $block->getProductListHtml() ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php } ?>`
```

Comment: you want completely remove side bar for some categories ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in the category configuration from the Magento admin.

> Catalog > Category > Select category to change the layout.

Please see attached screenshot for more information.

[image]

**Hope this helps!!!**